# How can a Google Cloud Python function access a private Python package

Tags: python, pip, google-cloud-functions

1. I am using Google Cloud Function using Python. Several other functions are in production.
2. However, for this, I have additionally created a custom Python package that is available on github as a *private* repo.
3. I need to install the package in the Google Function

### WHAT I HAVE DONE

1. I run the Google Function in local using `functions-framework`
2. I have a requirements.txt which has a link to the package. This is done by adding the following line to `requirements.txt`:

```
    -e git+https://github.com/<repo>/<project>#egg=<project>
```

3. I run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. And the package is successfully installed.
4. Now in the python code of the function using `import <pkg-name>` works and I am able to access all the functions.

### CHALLENGES WHEN PUSHING THE FUNCTION TO THE CLOUD

1. As per the documentation, to push the Cloud function to Google Cloud, I issue the command:

```
gcloud functions \
  deploy <function-name> \
  --trigger-http  \
  --entry-point <entry-function> \
  --runtime python37 \
  --project=<my-project>
```

As expected this gives an error because it does not have access to the private repo in git.

2. I created a Google Cloud Repository and linked it to the git repo, hoping that in some way I could specify that in the requirements.txt. Just do not know how.
3. I tried setting environment variables for username and password (not a good idea, I agree) in Google Cloud Function and specify them in the `requirements.txt` as:

```
    -e git+https://${AUTH_USER}:${AUTH_PASSWORD}@github.com/<repo>/<project>#egg=<project>
```

That too gave an error.

Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not access the private repo from cloud function. According to the official documentation:

> " **Using private dependencies**
>
> Dependencies are installed in a Cloud
> Build environment that does not provide access to SSH keys. Packages
> hosted in repositories that require SSH-based authentication must be
> vendored and uploaded alongside your project's code, as described in
> the previous section.
>
> You can use the pip install command with the -t DIRECTORY flag to copy
> private dependencies into a local directory before deploying your app,
> as follows:
>
> Copy your dependency into a local directory:
>
> ```
> pip install -t DIRECTORY DEPENDENCY
> ```
>
> Add an empty **init**.py file to the DIRECTORY directory to turn it
> into a module.
>
> Import from this module to use your dependency:
>
> ```
> import DIRECTORY.DEPENDENCY
> ```
>
> "

[Specifying dependencies in Python](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python)

Comment: Thanks @marian.vladoi. I did not know that. Ah that is so unfortunate. Let me check the documentation again.

Comment: after doing the `pip install -t <DIRECTORY> <DEPENDENCY>` I am failing at importing because my `<DEPENDENCY>` has dependencies of its own that are loaded into that directory but when doing the subsequent `import <DIRECTORY>.<DEPENDENCY>` it looks for them and (even though they are in the directory along with my primary dependency I desire) fails.  Does GCF autoload this into its path?  Should I be setting my path somewhere?

Comment: However if you are using artifact registry to host your private python packages you can.  The documentation in the above answer shows how.

Answer (score 10):

While @marian.viadoi was correct in the above comment viz. **Google Cloud Function cannot access a private git repo**, I have implemented a workaround and sharing just in case it is suitable. Here is what has been done:

1. The Python package was prepared as per the documentation  in (https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)
2. A binary distribution "whl" file was created using `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel`
3. This whl file was put in the google functions folder. I chose to put it under a `dist` folder of it.
4. In the `requirements.txt` I added the line: `./dist/xxxx.whl` to other dependencies required by the cloud function
5. Pushed the cloud function to GCP via the `gcloud deploy ..`
6. On successful installation, the package and its dependencies get automatically installed in the virtual environment of the cloud function

This **does not answer how to use a private repo** in Google Functions (which is not possible), but the above steps ensure that a private package can be easily shared and updated amongst different cloud functions.

Answer (score 3):

Your Method 3 (Git install with username and password) does work. But do remember to add them as `Build environment variables` rather than `Run environment variables`, as `pip install` happens during the build. If you have concerns using your personal credentials, you can get a deployment token instead (which is similar to personal credentials, with a username and password).

Comment: _THIS_ I've been trying all day to [use Secrets to obscure the password to a private pypi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71503882/google-cloud-secret-coming-out-as-missing), but it wasn't working. We finally figured out that it looked like the env var just wasn't available _yet_. It turns out Secrets are only available for run time, so for env vars needed in `requirements.txt`, we have to use the slightly-less-secret, but available-earlier build variables.