# Google Cloud Secret Coming Out As "(MISSING)"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-secret-manager

I've got a cloud function that needs to install dependencies from a private pypi.

- I've set up a secret called `pypi_password` for the project and given it the correct value.
- I've set up a service account to do deployment and given that service account `roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor`.
- I've added `--update-secrets PYPI_PASSWORD=pypi_password:latest` to my `deploy` command so the function should have access to the secret.
- I've added `--extra-index-url=https://account:${PYPI_PASSWORD}@pypi.my-company.com/pypi` to my function's `requirements.txt`.

When I deploy, I briefly see

[image]

before the during-deployment `pip install` fails because my credentials aren't right.

To investigate, I've gone and added an extra `${PYPI_PASSWORD}` in my `requirements.txt` to a portion that's not starred-out in `deploy`'s printed outputs, like: `--extra-index-url=https://${PYPI_PASSWORD}account:${PYPI_PASSWORD}@pypi.my-company.com/pypi`.

What I see is that the value of ${PYPI_PASSWORD} is coming out as `%7BPYPI_PASSWORD%!D(MISSING)`, which makes it seem like the environment variable doesn't exist.

But shouldn't the secret be accessible as an environment variable this way? This makes no sense to me, and I can't find a solution in the documentation.

Comment: According to [this google cloud blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-integrates-with-google-secret-manager), it's supposed to be as easy as what I've done. The value should be accessible as an env var all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that [I need to make a distinction between run time variables and build time variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71123169/2084503).

Basically, by trying to access a Secret in a `requirements.txt`, I'm trying to use it before it's fully defined and available. The only variables accessible when the dependencies are being installed are *build* variables.

If I put my password in one of those, it works, so this means Secrets are only available at run time, which makes them kind of useless for this. (*ahem*, Google)

I'm not so happy about still having the password in plain text for anyone who can view the function, but at least this gets it out of the source code.